# How do I get Doxygen to expand macros from include files?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have a number of multiline macros defined in a file called macros.h. In my doxyfile, I've got

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
PREDEFINED             =
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      =
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = NO
```

yet Doxygen still will not expand the macros in any source file that includes macros.h. I ran "doxygen -d Preprocessor doxyfile" to see the output of the preprocessor, and it outputs messages like:

```
#include macros.h: not found or already included! skipping...
```

Comment: This problem has been fixed in Doxygen 1.7.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've told your compiler about your include path, but you haven't told doxygen.  So it tries to open "macros.h" and gets a file-not-found error.

You need to properly set [INCLUDE_PATH](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_include_path) in your Doxyfile.

Comment: Indeed macros.h exists in a subdirectory of my source tree, but in my doxyfile, the INPUT tag is set to the base directory of my source tree.

Comment: @Phineas: In what directory is "macros.h" relative to the file that `#include`s it?

Comment: macros.h is in src/python, and Wrapper.h, the including file, is in src/extensions.

Comment: I just tried setting SEARCH_INCLUDES to YES and INCLUDE_PATH to src, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

@Ben: Have you actually gotten INCLUDE_PATH to work?

I understand the theory.  I have set up the INCLUDE_PATH as explained (in both absolute and relative forms) but to no avail.  I have set INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS to *.h.  Nonetheless, when processing my .cpp files Doxygen finds all of the headers in the INPUT directory yet fails to find any headers in my lib/ subdirectory.

The only solutions I have found are:

1) Create a symbolic link within the INPUT directory to each header in its lib/ subdirectory.  This is ugly and ungeneralizable.

2) Set the RECURSIVE tag to YES.  This is undesirable because now the entire contents INPUT's tests/ subdirectory get added to the generated documentation.

I am inclined to believe that INCLUDE_PATH functionality is simply broken (at least in version 1.7.1 that I am running).

Comment: I'm a _tiny_ bit late to the party here, but setting recursive to YES can be OK if you then set `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = test/*`. No more "tests" subdirectory ending up in your documentation.