# How can the classes defined in SC_MODULE be documented by Doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen, systemc

I am making the documentation of my app written in SystemC using Doxygen. The classes defined in the conventional C++ style are nicely hyperlinked, but the ones using SC_MODULE not. Is there any trick to persist using SC_MODULE (i.e. not changing to the conventional C++ style), and make its use equivalent with the conventional definition, at least from documentation point of view?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html) from the Doxygen documentation.

It requires the SystemC header to be available under the **INCLUDE_PATH**.
You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121333/how-do-i-get-doxygen-to-expand-macros-from-include-files) for similar question.